# Estimate execution time to run BigQuery if table volume is increased

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have been asked a requirement to estimate query execution time to run a query in GCP BigQuery. The current table has size of around 1 GB, and the query is straight-forward with simple aggregation. For example:-

```
select a, sum(b) from table1 group by a;
```

I can see the execution time for this query, also, I monitored the slots consumed during process which is around 5.
Now I am asked to find the execution time of same query if the table size is increased to 100 GB. I do not have that data now, but have been asked to provide estimate for execution time. Can we derive any method to extrapolate beyond given table to estimate execution time?
I am also assuming this is the only query which I will be executing in a given time. So all slots will be available for this query.

Comment: No, it's impossible. It depends on too many factor: the type of data, the slot available, the group by data type, the type of sum (float, int, bigint,...)...

Comment: You used the `group by` operation and thus your data needs to be sorted. This is not linear and at least has `O(n)=n*log(n)` computation cost. Going from 1 GB to 100 GB, will at least cost 700 times of computational time. (More slots then  execution time is only increased by maybe 10). However, there can be the case than some operation need additional reorganisation of data. This will increase the execution time much more. If possible generate some random data by  calculating  `select concat(a,T),sum(b) from table1,unnest(generate_array(1,100)) group by 1`